# Sqlite3/Node syntax error on Cloud9

Tags: node.js, sqlite, cloud9

I'm getting a syntax error running sqlite3 in my node project. If it matters, I'm running it in a Cloud9 workstation. My code's pretty simple, I think.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileGens = 'generators.db';

var existsGens = fs.existsSync(fileGens);

if(!existsGens) {
  console.log("Creating DB file 'generators'...");
  fs.openSync(fileGens, 'w');
}

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var dbGens = new sqlite3.Database(fileGens);

dbGens.serialize(function() {
  if(!existsGens) {
  console.log('Creating db...');
  }
  dbGens.run("CREATE TABLE TerrainFrequencies (Primary TEXT, Secondary TEXT, Tertiary TEXT, WildCards TEXT)");
  dbGens.run("INSERT INTO TerrainFrequencies VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 'Water', 'Hills', 'Forest', 'Mountains,Desert');

  console.log('About to select *');
  dbGens.all("SELECT * FROM TerrainFrequencies", function(err, row) {
    console.log('Selected...');
    console.log(row);
  });
});

dbGens.close();
```

I run it using *node index.js*, and my error...

```
Creating DB file 'generators'...
Creating db...
About to select *
events.js:141
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "Primary": syntax error
    at Error (native)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Primary is a reserved keyword / column name in sqlite. All day beating my head against the keyboard, solved it two minutes after I posted. Thanks for being a rubber duck, StackOverflow!